Flutter camera capturing video using camera after uploading in server that time some video failed for this error
capturing video using camera after uploading in server that time some video failed for this error
Error:

ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-4] ffmpeg failed to execute command: b"ffmpeg
version 5.1.4-0+deb12u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg
developers\n built with gcc 12 (Debian
12.2.0-14)\n configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb12u1 -- toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/
include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable�stripping
--enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable�libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable�libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable�libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libglslang
--enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame....

